# Link Styling won't apply to links for some reason

Tags: php, html, css

I Really feel stupid asking this question as it should and is a really basic knowledge to style links with CSS. 
And, today, I've been trying to style a link whole day with no success, stylesheet doesn't want to apply to the wanted looks onto my links.
This is the stylesheet public A:

```
A:link {text-decoration: none; color: white;}
A:visited {text-decoration: none; color: white;}
A:active {text-decoration: none; color: white;}
A:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: red;}
```

This is the block if code I am trying to get it work with(It's in a while loop querying the database)

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, body, category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=posts.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC");
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);    
while($query->fetch()):?>
    <?php $lastspace = strrpos($body, ' ');?>
    <article>
    <h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
    <?php echo  $category;?>
    <?php echo "<hr>";?>
    <p><?php echo nl2br (substr($body,0,$lastspace)). "<a href='post.php?id=$post_id'>Read More</a>"?></p>
    <?php echo "<hr>"?>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Okay, That's it. What did I do wrong/How to fix this?

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: As an habit, I would write a:link instead of A:link. But yes, post the portion of code where there is the integration of the css.

Comment: there might be another CSS selector with higher specificity overriding this.  can't tell without seeing the whole page.

Comment: the URL is http://wrya.x10host.com/highflyer/index.php, also, the links get styled once, but once clicked all the styling disappears.

Comment: @chrisgonzalez No it isn't. What makes you say that?

Comment: @user2715244 They work for me. What browser and.or operating system are you using? Also, have you cleared your cache? Your browser might be caching an old version of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cache worked. I Should Have thought of that before.